# first time running application slow from dll

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I'm new to C#.

What I want to ask is I create a form and compile it into **dll** and try to call from it from another application (from company application).

What I want to ask is, when I try to open my form for the **first time** it takes a while (like 1-2 minute) and then I close the form (**not application**) and re-try to open the form again for the **second time** its much more faster than the first time.

**but** if I close the application **completely** and re-open my form for the **first time** it takes a while (like 1-2 minute).

for the **dll** itself, are selecting database. The code as below

```
public partial class Genre : Form
{
    SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(class.Conn);
    DataTable dt_main = new DataTable();

    Bitmap gbr_inf = new Bitmap(Properties.Resources.info_icon, 25, 25);
    Bitmap gbr_error = new Bitmap(Properties.Resources.close, 25, 25);

    RepositoryItemComboBox repositoryItemComboBox1 = new RepositoryItemComboBox();
    RepositoryItemComboBox repositoryItemComboBox2 = new RepositoryItemComboBox();


    public Genre()
    {            
        InitializeComponent();
        repositoryItemComboBox1.ButtonClick += RepositoryItemComboBox1_ButtonClick;
        repositoryItemComboBox2.ButtonClick += RepositoryItemComboBox2_ButtonClick;
    }

 private void Genre_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SDB();         
        fill_repo();
    }

 public void SDB()
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        try
        {
            dt_main.Clear();
            myConnection.Open();

            command.Connection = myConnection;
            command.CommandText = "Select * from Genre with (nolock) order by code";                
            adapter.SelectCommand = command;
            adapter.Fill(dt_main);
            gridControl1.DataSource = dt_main;               
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("error" + ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            myConnection.Close();
        }
    }

  public void fill_repo()
    {
        DataTable dtrepo = new DataTable();
        dtrepo.Clear();
        dtrepo = dt_main.Copy();

        for (int i = 0; i < dtrepo.Rows.Count; i++)
        {                                
            string code = dtrepo.Rows[i]["code"].ToString();
            string genre = dtrepo.Rows[i]["genre"].ToString();

            if (!repositoryItemComboBox1.Items.Contains(code))
            {
                repositoryItemComboBox1.Items.Add(code);
            }
            if (!repositoryItemComboBox2.Items.Contains(genre))
            {
                repositoryItemComboBox2.Items.Add(genre);
            }

        }
    }

 private void gridView1_CustomRowCellEdit(object sender, CustomRowCellEditEventArgs e)
    {           
        if (e.Column.FieldName == "code" && view.IsFilterRow(e.RowHandle))
        {
            e.RepositoryItem = repositoryItemComboBox1;
        }
        if (e.Column.FieldName == "genre" && view.IsFilterRow(e.RowHandle))
        {
            e.RepositoryItem = repositoryItemComboBox2;
        }          
    }
}
```

what seems to be the problem ?

Comment: I don’t see a link to DevExpress. Is that all that’s in the DLL? The first time code is needed the libraries are loaded. If there are a lot of dependencies doing something it will take time. But over a minute? Have you tried debugging line by line to see what’s happening?

Comment: If you are selecting records from a database, it it normal for the application to run longer on the first run; after that, the records are already in the cache, so they can be selected faster in the following runs.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen well, for importing i don't type it in this post. it got 13 dependencies mainly devexpress. for debuging i don't see any error

Comment: @SebastianHofmann i know that. let me give you an example form a and form b. form a like above and form b much more select than form a. lets say i open the application for first time and open my form A first ( it takes 1 minute)  then i open my form B (it takes less than 1 minute).  and vice versa. if i open the application for first time and open my form B first (it takes more than 1 minute) then i open my form A (it takes less than 1minute)

Answer (score 0):

When you call `SDB`:

```
public void SDB()
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    try
    {
        dt_main.Clear();
        myConnection.Open();

        command.Connection = myConnection;
        command.CommandText = "Select * from Genre with (nolock) order by code";                
        adapter.SelectCommand = command;
        adapter.Fill(dt_main);
        gridControl1.DataSource = dt_main;               
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("error" + ex);
    }
    finally
    {
        myConnection.Close();
    }
}
```

You are copying *all fields and all rows* from the Genre table and putting them into the `dt_main` DataTable. This could be an expensive operation depending on how big the Genre table is.

If you want your application to perform well, you should generally avoid very large queries by selecting only the fields and rows you are interested in working with at any given time. In this case, you are only using the `code` and `genre` fields, so you could get much better performance by using

```
"Select code, genre with (nolock) order by code"
```

In addition, you are copying the entire table *again* just before you populate the dropdowns:

```
dtrepo = dt_main.Copy();
```

This is totally unnecessary.

Caching the data is also important so you don't hit the database on every form load. This you are doing (accidentally) but you really should have a better plan for doing so.

Comment: sorry i don't think the query impact more than this. because the record itself less than 100. from what i research is it because of cold/warm startup ?
you can see the previous comment, what i have tried to simulation this.